# Bulk insert into SQL table from CSV using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I need to bulk insert data into `SQL` from a `csv` file.  In SQL I use the command:

```
bulk insert InputTestData
from 'D:\Project\UnitTestProjct\RGTestingToolTestProject\NUnitTestProject\RGTestToolDB\InputTestData.csv'
with
(   CODEPAGE ='RAW',
    rowterminator='\n',
    fieldterminator = '\t'
)
```

The above command is working and inserts data when using SQL query analyzer, but, throws an error when executed from `C#` using the code given below :

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                    builder.Append("bulk insert " + objectName + " from ");
                                    builder.Append("'" + ResourceFilePath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + objectPath + "'");
                                    builder.Append(" with");
                                    builder.Append(" (");                                       
                                    builder.Append(" rowterminator='\n',");
                                    builder.Append(" fieldterminator = '\t'");
                                    builder.Append(" )");

                                    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(transaction, CommandType.Text, builder.ToString());
```

It throws the error:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 8 (IsBaselineTest).
```

The query generated by C# code is also working fine in `SQL` query analyzer :

```
bulk insert InputTestData from 'D:\Project\UnitTestProjct\RGTestingToolTestProject\NUnitTestProject\\RGTestToolDB\InputTestData.csv' with ( rowterminator='
', fieldterminator = '  ',CODEPAGE ='RAW' )
```

Please let me know if you have required `CSV` and `SQL` table structure

Please help on above.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tested query generate by your `StringBuilder` in query analyzer ?

Comment: Yes its working,I have update that query also in question block

Comment: the string you build in c# is missing the parameter `CODEPAGE`. if you add it back does anything changes?

Comment: @Paolo I have already tried to add `CODEPAGE` into stringbuilder

Comment: I can't give you a direct answer but you might try using the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy class which is designed for this scenario.

Comment: But using `SqlBulkCopy ` firstly read the csv file by `streamreader` then insert,it might be performance hit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to escape the backslash's for the line and field terminators, since it looks like the string already converted them to the actual characters 0x10 and 0x09.  I would think it has to be builder.Append(" rowterminator='\\n',");
      builder.Append(" fieldterminator = '\\t'");

Comment: Hi Mike your suggestion is works,it helps me indeed,Please post same in answer,so that i can accept.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to escape the backslash's for the line and field terminators, since it looks like the string already converted them to the actual characters 0x10 and 0x09. I would think it has to be

```
builder.Append(" rowterminator='\\n',"); 
builder.Append(" fieldterminator = '\\t'");
```

Answer (score 0):

i just completed a similar task using SqlBulkCopy as suggested by some comment.

my source is a XML document but the situation is pretty similar.

the solution i developed is a web interface to upload the data, some code to put it in a datatable and then a call to a SqlBulkCopy to insert into a temporary table.

the last step is a query that insert the data into the final table handling duplicates and performing some validation.

here is some code (is vb.net actually):

```
' create in memory datatable
' my choice has been to have the same datatype for all fields
Dim sapCustomer As DataTable = New DataTable("customer")
For Each SAPFieldName As String In SAPColMapping
  sapCustomer.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(SAPFieldName, GetType(System.String)))
Next

' fill previous table using xml data
For Each SapRow As XmlNode In RowList.SelectNodes("ROW")
  ... more code here to translate xml into datatable...
Next

' create temporary table on sql server
Using dbCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
  dbCmd.Connection = dbConn
  dbCmd.Transaction = dbTran
  dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  dbCmd.CommandText = "create table #tempTable (your fields here)"
  dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
End Using

' fill temp table
Using sbc As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(dbConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, dbTran)
  sbc.BatchSize = 1000
  ' no explicit mapping between source and destination fields
  ' because both tables have the very same field names
  sbc.DestinationTableName = "#tempTable"
  sbc.WriteToServer(sapCustomer)
End Using

' handle the steps needed to copy/move the data to the final destination
Using dbCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
  dbCmd.Connection = dbConn
  dbCmd.Transaction = dbTran
  dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  dbCmd.CommandText = "insert into finaltable select field1, field2 from #tempTable"
  dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
End Using
```

the above code succesfully handles xml documents 50mb+ with 50k records in 1 min.

the heavy task is the copy of the data from xml to datatable: a bunch of secs for upload,  40 sec for xml -> datatable and 2 sec for the database processing.

if your data is in a more 'datatable friendly' format you may achieve better performances easily.